# Is it possible to make the keyboard module work with pygame and threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My friend challenged me to make a small program that allows the user to press a button on a Xbox controller and have it do multiple functions on the keyboard (like reWASD). I thought I almost made it to the end and found the having keyboard.press() and keyboard.release() wouldn't do its function. Is there any possible way to make it do what I hoped it to do. Sorry for the bad English I am freshmen and its 1 am and I am new to stakoverflow formatting.

Here is my code.

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
import pygame
import threading
pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BLACK = pygame.Color('black')
WHITE = pygame.Color('white')
stall = 0

def stall1():
    global stall
    while stall == 1:
        keyboard.press('a')
        keyboard.release('a')
        stall = 0



# This is a simple class that will help us print to the screen.
# It has nothing to do with the joysticks, just outputting the
# information.
class TextPrint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

    def tprint(self, screen, textString):
        textBitmap = self.font.render(textString, True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(textBitmap, (self.x, self.y))
        self.y += self.line_height

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.line_height = 15

    def indent(self):
        self.x += 10

    def unindent(self):
        self.x -= 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 700))

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

textPrint = TextPrint()


while True:  # making a loo
    t = threading.Thread(target=stall1())

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()

    # Get count of joysticks.
    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

    textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of joysticks: {}".format(joystick_count))
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Button Pressed")
            if joystick.get_button(0):
                stall = 1
            # Control Left Motor using L2
            elif joystick.get_button(2):
                # Control Right Motor using R2
                print('yote')
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Button Released")

    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
        joystick.init()

        # Get the name from the OS for the controller/joystick.
        name = joystick.get_name()

        # Usually axis run in pairs, up/down for one, and left/right for
        # the other.
        axes = joystick.get_numaxes()
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 20 frames per second.
    clock.tick(20)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit()
```

Just so I can try to explain simply. I want press the a button and have it type something. Using threading, pygame, and keyboard. Sorry, im new to coding and formatting on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why is your code creating a new thread every iteration of the main loop?  (and re-initialising the joysticks).  Do you need to use the thread at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

> ```py
> t = threading.Thread(target=stall1())
> ```

does not do what you expect it to do, because `stall1()` is a call to the function `stall1`. That means the function will be called immediately in the main thread and the return value of the function will be passed to the keyword argument `target` (`None` in this case).

You have to pass the function object (`stall1`) to the argument:

```py
t = threading.Thread(target=stall1)
```

Change the function `stall1`, so that it runs as long a state `thread_running` is set:

```py
stall = 0
thread_running = True
def stall1():
    global stall
    while thread_running:
        if stall == 1:
            stall = 0
            keyboard.press('a')
            keyboard.release('a')
```

Start the thread and initialize the joystick before the main application loop:

```py
t = threading.Thread(target=stall1)
t.start()

joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()
if joystick_count > 0:
    joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    joystick.init()

run = True
while run:

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()
    textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of joysticks: {}".format(joystick_count))

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          thread_running = False  
          run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(chr(event.key)) # print key (triggered from 'stall1')

        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Button Pressed")
            if joystick.get_button(0):
                stall = 1
            elif joystick.get_button(2):
                print('yote')
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Button Released")

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
```